# Is it possible to a dynamically created field be required AND unique in register form?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I've added a new field using the custom field generator for customers feature that comes by default in Opencart 2.x [like this](https://www.templatemonster.com/help/opencart-2-x-how-to-add-custom-fields-to-contact-form.html).

The idea is to have a single "document number" like single email in each registration where both should work equally being required AND unique.

There's anyway to check this dynamically created field against the database and accomplish the requirement? Or, if not, could you please provide some starting point for a custom thing?

As a complimentary info, here goes a screenshot of our admin panel:
[image: admin-oc-2.3.0.2]

Comment: Have you got any experience coding in PHP? You haven't shared any example code or anything that you've attempted to do so it's difficult to determine what sort of help you require.

Answer (score 0):

You must PHP coding skill to the same.
Customization process is :
1) Edit register controller based on new field.  Index and validate function will be customize in controller.
2) Add keywords in register.php language file.
3) Change in customer model and edit addcustomer function to save the same field.
4) Add form field in register.tpl file. 
5) create a column in customer table in your running database.

hope it may help you to create a new field.

Comment: I apologize for delaying my response :v. 
Ended-up creating an entirely new field following the default theme code trough all MVC structure.